# Tweak showlabels/showkeys - wrap the label

Tags: line-breaking, marginpar, showkeys, showlabels

Can `showlabels` wrap the label in the margin? A very similar question is [showlabels: wrap labels in marginpar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60693/showlabels-wrap-labels-in-marginpar), but the solution of @DavidCarlisle does not solve the more general case. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{default}
  \label{fig:a very very very long and detailed label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When adding the package `showkeys` the output is: 
[image]

Similar problem occurs with the `showlabels` package (whether the hack of @DavidCarlisle is used or not):
[image]

So, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Why would you ever want a label that long? I've used latex for 25 years and never put a space in a label?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I guess this will turn into a new question...

Comment: Did you find any optimum solution for this? :) I have the same problem for labeling equations. :)

Answer (score 8):

In order to split a long label without spaces, you can use the `\seqsplit` command from the [seqsplit package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit). The following is an adaption of [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148579/tweak-showlabels-showkeys-wrap-the-label/148613#148613) and also shows the necessity of wrapping long labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%showframe, % show helper lines
            paperwidth=10cm, paperheight=7cm,
            hmargin=24mm,vmargin=4mm, marginparwidth=17mm,
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{xstring}

\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{%
\noexpandarg%
% instead of \textvisiblespace you can also put in ~
% if you want to keep a plain space at space characters
\StrSubstitute{\(\{\)#1\(\}\)}{ }{\textvisiblespace}[\TEMP]%
\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\normalfont\small\ttfamily\expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\TEMP}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    (a\cdot b ) \cdot c = a\cdot (b\cdot c)
    \label{eq:groupassociativity}
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{default}
  \label{fig:a very very very long and detailed label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: long labels with spaces]

For the spaces, one needs to [replace the spaces within the seqsplit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273846/46552), either by `~` for keeping a space or by something else like `\textvisiblespace` to visualize it better.

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to accommodate labels containing spaces as well?---I mean just like treating the spaces as any other character and break wherever the line width is exhausted.

Comment: Yes, it's possible after a slight modification. I've extended the answer above.

Answer (score 7):

Having labels like this is really a misuse of the label system, labels are intended to be short symbolic names, but anyway

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\normalfont\small\ttfamily#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{default}
  \label{fig:a very very very long and detailed label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this also work for the following `\label{fig:a-very-very-very-long-and-detailed-label}`? In particular treat the `-` as spaces. I guess it can be tweaked.

Comment: @Dror `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` then define the command as `\fbox{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\normalfont\small\url{#1}}}}`

Comment: The analogous command in the showlabels package is `\showlabelsetlabel`, but, like David, I'm sceptical that a label this long is a good idea.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your solution does not work in 2-column mode eg. with the IEEEtran class

Comment: @Krishna I just changed article` to `IEEEtran` in the above and it worked for me, If something gives an error make a test fie and post a new question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know. I had to do `\fbox{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\path{#1}}}}`  to get it to work. The key thing missing here is `\path`. Actually, you were the one who wrote this other incantation in your answer to a duplicate question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342560/showkeys-labels-out-of-margin).

Comment: @Krishna you might need `\path` if the label is not hyphenatable or, as here, has spaces, but that is completely unrelated to IEEEtran or double column