# Showkeys package with very small margins

Tags: showkeys

Hi I am working on an appendix which  has very large tables. Since I have these tables , I have narrowed the margins as much as possible so that they fit properly.

I am also using the showkeys package to cross-reference easily the appendix with the main article but since my margins are to narrow, I can't seem to print the complete label. I was wondering, is there a way to print the labels in vertical mode? Here is my minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{margin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Example figure}
\begin{center}
\missingfigure[figwidth=0.7\textwidth]{Testing a long text string}
\end{center}
\label{add:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces me an output like this:

[image]

You can see the label cropped at the left side. As you may see, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148579/tweak-showlabels-showkeys-wrap-the-label) does not work for me. Is there any way to show the complete label without having to reduce the margins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `url` package with as many breaking options turned on as possible and making a fixed width box placed appropriately can help.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{margin=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.1cm,marginparsep=0.1cm}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[obeyspaces,hyphens,spaces]{url}
\renewcommand*{\showkeyslabelformat}[1]{%
   \fbox{\vbox{\hsize=1.1cm\normalfont\small\url{#1}\par}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Example figure}
\begin{center}
\missingfigure[figwidth=0.7\textwidth]{Testing a long text string}
\end{center}
\label{add:label-long with space}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you need more break points in the labels then you can try passing such information to the `url` algorithm.  Also making the label ragged-right can help with the spacing:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{margin=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.1cm,marginparsep=0.1cm}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,hyphens,spaces]{url}
\renewcommand*{\showkeyslabelformat}[1]{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks%  save the current one
  \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
  \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
  \do\Y\do\Z}%
  \fbox{\vbox{\hsize=1cm\RaggedRight\noindent\normalfont\small\url{#1}\par}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Example figure}
\begin{center}
\missingfigure[figwidth=0.7\textwidth]{Testing a long text string}
\end{center}
\label{add:label-long with space}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:long-label-without-space}
  x=y.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would work if I could use spaces. However, my labels don't use spaces, I did not decide the label names and I am not authorized to change them :/

Comment: Further extension now provided - does this help?

Comment: @AndrewSwann, your extension turned out to be crucial to me. I also changed "small" to "tiny". Now displaying the labels in the margins in a draft is a viable option for me.