# Trouble nesting multiple commands using \newcommandx

Tags: color, expansion

First Question in this forum, so go easy on me :)
I made a few meeting minutes documents for my business and I wanted a custom command for adding a note in a document. I wanted the color of the text and the text box width to be optional. Also, want this to be a package I can call instead of putting this command code in every document I want to use it. Below is my attempt at a solution.

Here is my .sty file

```
\ProvidesPackage{pnutscommands}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommandx{\colornote}[3][1=red, 2=3in]{%
    \begin{minipage}{#2}
    \textcolor{#1}{\seqsplit{\StrSubstitute{#3}{ }{~}}}
    \end{minipage}
    }
```

Here is my .txt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pnutscommands}

\begin{document}

\colornote[blue][5in]
{17823941dsfdsfdsf 23471239047123 9407123408917234890123748912034712985712389012351}

\colornote
{17823941237490812347123904712389 dsdsfdsfdsfdfs 23748912034712985712389012351}

\end{document}
```

This code works if you replace `\StrSubstitute{#3}{ }{~}}` with `#3`. The issue was that `\seqsplit` removes spaces in the string. So I tried \StrSubstitute but it returns an error that I'm unfamiliar with.

```
% Console output:
! Use of \@xs@StrSubstitute@@ doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                              #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.7 ...408917234890123748912034712985712389012351}
```

Can someone help me either fix this error or point me to a better solution?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I actually ran into a few of your comments while working on this new command. Seems you're quite active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `\newcommandx`. You have to first do the substitutions and then apply `\seqsplit` to the string you got.

There's also the complication of avoiding that `xstring` expands too much.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommandx{\colornote}[3][1=red, 2=3in]{%
  \begin{minipage}{#2}
  \noexpandarg
  \StrSubstitute{#3}{ }{~}[\TEMP]%
  \textcolor{#1}{\expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\TEMP}}%
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\colornote[blue][5in]
{17823941dsfdsfdsf 23471239047123 9407123408917234890123748912034712985712389012351}

\colornote
{17823941237490812347123904712389 dsdsfdsfdsfdfs 23748912034712985712389012351}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The mandatory `expl3` implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colornote}{O{red}O{3in}m}
 {
  \begin{minipage}{#2}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \nobreakspace }
  \breslend_color_seqsplit:Vn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \end{minipage}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \breslend_color_seqsplit:nn
 {
  \textcolor{#2}{\seqsplit{#1}}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \breslend_color_seqsplit:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\colornote[blue][5in]
{17823941dsfdsfdsf 23471239047123 9407123408917234890123748912034712985712389012351}

\colornote
{17823941237490812347123904712389 dsdsfdsfdsfdfs 23748912034712985712389012351}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll continue on with your first solution. I'm trying to expand from this basic example to more complex commands. Appreciate the help @egreg !