# Error from interactions between equation environments, \eqref, showkeys, hyperref, and seqsplit

Tags: showkeys

I got an error which I was able to trim down to the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{\seqsplit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{\eqref{1}}
\begin{equation}
  \label{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The error message says that:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\SQSPL@scan ->\futurelet \SQSPL@next 
                                     \SQSPL@scani 
l.13 \end{document}
```

Basically, I was trying to do something like what's explained here:

[Tweak showlabels/showkeys - wrap the label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148579/tweak-showlabels-showkeys-wrap-the-label)

and found out that it causes this error.

I would appreciate it if anyone can explain to me what is really happening here, and what are possible solutions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it doesn't error for me in a current tex system.

Comment: If I replace `\label{2}` with `\label{1}`, your test document compiles fine on MacTeX2023, with all updates applied, as well.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Try deleting the `aux` file and compiling your MWE again.

Comment: Okay, I'll update my TeX release and retry. Btw @Mico that didn't help.

Comment: @schtandard That also didn't help, but I'll retry after the update is finished, which is unfortunately painfully slow! Thanks guys for the help anyway.

Comment: Ha, this indeed works after I updated my TeX to the latest one. Thank you guys!